# How to move to next activtity with bundle the touch event is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

guys in my project i need to click the item on the list and move to next activity using bundle i need to carry some data also, but i have some issue..
 Please help me to move to next activity i can't understand what is the mistake i did,when i click on the item it is not even responding..
    here i just use "e_name.setText("hiiii")" for testing purpose its not working.
AT THE END I HAVE MENTIONED MY LAYOUT CODES ALSO.
if possible please send me a link to learn more about custom adapter and list view..

```
//Main activity.java
       package com.prematix.ashok.friday_9;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText e_name, e_desig, e_salary;
        Button save;
        String itemNames[];
        String itemDescriptions[];
        ListView itemsListView;
        ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            e_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_name);
            e_desig = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_desig);
            e_salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_salary);
            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
            itemsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //create adapter object
                    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), generateItemsList());

                    //set custom adapter as adapter to our list view
                    itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                private ArrayList<Item> generateItemsList() {
                    itemNames = new String[]{e_name.getText().toString()};
                    itemDescriptions = new String[]{e_desig.getText().toString()};
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
                        list.add(new Item(itemNames[i], itemDescriptions[i]));
                    }
                    return list;
                }
            });
            itemsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                  e_name.setText("hiiiii");
                }
            });
          //  ListView itemsListView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_items);

        }
    }
    //CustommListAdapter.java

    package com.prematix.ashok.friday_9;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by ${Nagaveni} on 2017-06-09.
     */

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items){
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if(view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_row_items, viewGroup, false);
            }
                //get current item to be displayed
                Item currentitem = (Item)getItem(i);
                //get the text view for item name and item designation
                TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView designation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.desig);
                TextView salary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.salary);
                //sets the text for item name and item designation from the current item object
                name.setText(currentitem.getNames());
                designation.setText(currentitem.getDesignation());
                salary.setText("10,000");
                //returns the view for current row

            return view;
        }
    }

   //here is my layout code
layout_list_view_items.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="designation"
        android:id="@+id/desig"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="salary"
        android:id="@+id/salary"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 //activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.prematix.ashok.friday_9.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/ed_name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Designation"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/ed_desig" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Salary"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/ed_salary" />

    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/save" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mylist"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout code.

Comment: where can i post the layout code...here in comment i can't post it..

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: yeah i have updated bro... please take look again..